# C# and SqlDataAdapter

Tags: c#, sqldataadapter

```
 SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection("Data Source=m**-PC; Initial Catalog=Mydb; Integrated Security=True");
 DataSet set = new DataSet();
 SqlDataAdapter data = new SqlDataAdapter();
 connect .Open();
 data.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT Yazi FROM Ozgecmis", connect);
 data.Fill(set, "Yazi");
 connect.Close();
 int sayi = set.Tables["Yazi"].Columns.Count;
 TextBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(sayi);
```

I'd take data the dataset and add table so I'd learn to count the table of colums and write texbox1

I don't take sayi but I don't have error.What is the wrong ?

Comment: Please try and rephrase your question!

Comment: please rephrase your question, so that we may understand what actually the problem is, thanks

Comment: The number of columns here is always going to be exactly 1...

Answer (score 1):

Change the code to

```
    SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection("Data Source=m**-PC; Initial Catalog=Mydb; Integrated Security=True");
    DataSet set = new DataSet();
    SqlDataAdapter data = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT Yazi FROM Ozgecmis", connect);
    data.Fill(set, "Yazi");
    int sayi = set.Tables["Yazi"].Columns.Count;
    TextBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(sayi);
```

You have to fill the select command of the data adapter, not the insert command, to read from the database to the dataset. This can be done with `data.SelectCommand` or in the constructor `new SqlDataAdapter(...)` like in the above code. Further the opening and closing of the connection is done automatically by the data adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
    SqlDataAdapter data = new SqlDataAdapter("SQL QUERY HERE");
    ...
    TextBox1.Text = set.Tables[0].Columns.Count.ToString();
```

if it not work please write an error message ?